# Laravel, a problem when using the query builder value() method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

here is the **users** table:

```
id  name                        email
1   Tia Fahey                   kathleen31@example.org
2   Ms. Sabrina Hahn III        alejandra62@example.net
3   Andrew Ullrich              germaine40@example.net
4   Mrs. Marion Gutmann V       vita77@example.com
5   Letha Moen Jr.              koepp.rigoberto@example.net
6   Prof. Ottilie Wilkinson IV  tbode@example.com
```

when I use

```
$id=DB::table('users')->value('id');
$name=DB::table('users')->value('name');
$email=DB::table('users')->value('email');
echo $id."  ".$name."  ".$email;
// echo:
// 2  Tia Fahey  alejandra62@example.net
```

Why does it get the id and email from the second row and the name form the first row?

Comment: this may help you ,this is not good idea your fetch id,name,email seperatly write a single query then read it once by object    https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries

Comment: use  $id=DB::table('user')->find('2') you do looks like your fetching data in wrong way

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it get the id and email from the second row and the name form the first row?

Because no condition was specified making the selection random.
You can use one of these:

```
 // Returns directly the name column of the first row
$name = DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->value('name');

// Retrieves a collection containing only the name column of the first row
$name = DB::table('users')->orderBy('id')->first('name');

// Retrieves a collection containing only the name column of the last row
$name = DB::table('users')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first('name');

// Retrieves a collection containing the name field for the row with id: $id.
$id = 1;
$name = DB::table('users')->find($id, 'name');
```

If you wanna retrieve the values of a certain row, no need to query the database multiple times: query on e then accesse the columns values, for example:

```
$id = 1;
$user = DB::table('users')->find($id);
$name = $user->name;
$email = $user->email;
```

Comment: Thank you! I also notice that the query builder's first() method selects the first row in random too, like DB::table('user')->first('id') returned 2

Comment: Yes. `first` just tells the database that you want only want row, meaning, it adds `LIMIT 1` to the query. So the randomness of the result of the query is not from Laravel but rather from the database. `DB::table('user')->first('id')` in SQL will be: `SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 1. And the database decides which row to return (because there is no condition that forces it to return a certain row). If you want specifically the first row, you should put a constraint like `WHERE id = ?` or `ORDER BY id`.

Comment: In Laravel it will be: `DB::table('user')->orderBy('id')->first('id')` or `DB::table('user')->where('name', 'the name')->first('id')`